# key in ruby new hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-1.9.2

There is a weird issue with Ruby 1.9.2's new hash syntax. How can I put any Object as key in hash in 1.9.2?

in 1.8.7 hash it works:

```
a="b" 
{"a" => "some",a => "another value",:a => "3rd value"}
```

But in 1.9.2 > We can't (or how can we if I'm wrong?")

1.9.2 hash:

```
{a: "some"} =>  {:a=>"s"} #it convert to old hash format
```

but

```
a="a" 
{a: "..."} # This doesn't work

{"a": "some value"} => syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
from /home/naveed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'

{1: "s"} =>

SyntaxError: (irb):11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC {1: "s"}
```

Comment: You know that the old syntax is still valid in 1.9, right? It's not a replacement, it's an addition.

Comment: Yeah old syntax is still here and it will be..I don't like to put too many rockets in my code :) => => => Dusss Duss

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between `:key => "value"` and `key: "value"` assignments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-key-value-and-key-value-assignments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9 you are allowed to put colon `:` **only after symbols** that are used as keys!

**Any** object can use the arrow `=>`, even symbols.

Comment: {a:"s","a"=>"d"}  don't looks pretty +1 for  ": only after symbols "

Comment: Rails extensively uses symbols as keys, so appearing hashes as yours isn't too probable. But of course, Rails isn't the only Ruby's application...

Answer (score 3):

To say this another way, the new feature isn't a new general hash syntax, it's a specific tweak for writing hashes where the keys are symbol literals. `{a: 1}` is just a shortcut for `{:a => 1}`, and that's all. If you have anything else as keys, you have to use the regular syntax.