# Difference between :symbol => versus symbol:

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between `:key => "value"` and `key: "value"` assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-key-value-and-key-value-assignments)
>   [key in ruby new hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293936/key-in-ruby-new-hash)

I am reading some rails code and I see a method can be called

```
foo(:var1 => 'hello', :var2 => 'world')
```

or

```
foo(var1: 'hello', var2: 'world')
```

Both seems to work exactly the same. Is there any difference? Which is the better practice?

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate comments. I tried searching but I'm not sure how to search when there are symbols like : and => involved

Comment: Use Symbolhound.com to search for syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean the same thing. The latter is new Ruby 1.9 syntax inspired by JavaScript. Use the former if you need to stay compatible with Ruby 1.8. Otherwise it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

In a method call, both work exactly the same, but when you make a hash, they will have diferences

```
# in a method call
foo( :param => 'p' )
# mean the same thing
foo( param: 'p' )

# but in a Hash construction, they will have diferences

# here the key will always be a Symbol
hash = { symb: value }
# but here the key can be anything
hash = { 1 => "1" }
hash = { "1" => 1 }
```

Comment: Uh, what? There's no difference in a method call containing a hash vs. a normal hash construction.

Comment: You're right, and I'm saying this in the answer. @AndrewMarshall .

Comment: No, you're not. You say, "when you make a hash, they will have diferences" (sic), which is not true. You say this right after saying there are not difference in a method call.

Comment: You see the code example? And don't understand my explain? @AndrewMarshall

Comment: Your code example includes no method calls, but your text explanation talks about them, so the code you give wouldn't change it.