# Difference between :symbol and symbol:?

Tags: ruby

Just going through a tutorial, and thought somewhere I saw

```
first_name:
```

And another place

```
:first_name
```

Is this right? What is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between `:key => "value"` and `key: "value"` assignments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-key-value-and-key-value-assignments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash syntax changed in Ruby 1.9.2 to get closer to json.

So:

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

Is the same as:

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

In all other cases, the colon must come first.

Answer (score 5):

:first_name is a symbol, while first_name: is a Hash key in the new Ruby 1.9.2 syntax.

Hash keys are then converted to symbols:

```
>> a = { foo: 10 , bar: 20 }
=> {:foo=>10, :bar=>20}
```

It is the same as writing:

```
>> a = { :foo => 10, :bar => 20 }
=> {:foo=>10, :bar=>20}
```