# Difference between prepend and append of colon ( :item vs item:)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between appending and prepending a colon in ruby?

Example:

```
#In rails you often have things like this:
has_many :models, dependent: :destroy
```

Why does `dependent:` have an appended colon, but `:models` and `:destroy` have a prepended colon? What is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between the \`:key => "value"\` and \`key: "value"\` hash notations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a new syntax in Ruby 1.9 for defining symbols that are the keys in a hash.

Both prepended and appended `:`'s define a `symbol`, but the latter is only valid during the initialization of a hash.

You can think of a [symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html) as a lightweight string constant.

It is equivalent to

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

Prior to 1.9, hashes were defined with a syntax that is slightly more verbose and awkward to type:

```
hash = {
   :key => "value",
   :another_key => 4
}
```

They simplified it in 1.9:

```
hash = {
   key: "value",
   another_key: 4
}
```

If you are ever writing a module you want to use on Ruby prior to 1.9, make sure you use the older syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Since Ruby allows you to omit parenthesis `()`and in some cases curly braces `{}` it might not be very obvious but the above code is actually looking like this:

`has_many(:models, { dependent: :destroy } )`

Now, it means that `has_many` takes two arguments, one being a symbol `:`, an immutable string if you will, and also a hash where the `dependent` is the key and `destroy` is the value; also maybe seen as `:dependent => destroy`.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases the colon indicates a symbol, but appending it is shorthand for when the symbol is a key in a hash.

```
dependent: :destroy
```

is the same as

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

The "appended" colon is simply the new common way of displaying hashes in 1.9.

`dependent: :destroy` is the same thing as `:dependent => :destroy`

On the other hand, a "prepended" colon indicates a symbol data type in Ruby.