# colon hash notation doesn't work

Tags: ruby

This line works:

```
<%= link_to "About", pages_about_path, :class => "name" %>
```

while this doesn't:

```
<%= link_to "About", pages_about_path, class : "name" %>
```

Aren't both equivalent hash notations? The examples shown in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) also use the second notation.

Comment: Nowhere in the API docs does it use the second format (because it’s invalid Ruby).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It is a silly mistake.. :) OP did..

Comment: BTW, the two notations [are not equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675314/479863).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put one unnecessary space between `class` and `:`. So try the following:

```
 { class: "name"}
```

**Corrected one:-**

```
<%= link_to "About", pages_about_path, class: "name" %>
```