# Explain hash rocket in this context

Tags: ruby

I've just written this code, that works although I am not entirely sure why:

```
scope = scope.where(Sequel.qualify(:meeting_graphs, :id) => query.ids)
```

I am specifically talking about the hash rocket.

Previously the code was this, which makes perfect sense:

```
scope = scope.where(id: query.ids)
```

First thing I do not understand is why it does this not work when I replace the hash rocket with a colon which I thought was the preferred syntax:

```
scope = scope.where(Sequel.qualify(:meeting_graphs, :id): query.ids)
```

Sequel.qualify returns an object which also confuses me as I thought it would return a symbol.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- that works although I am not entirely sure why

  As long as `Sequel.qualify(:meeting_graphs, :id)` is valid, it can be a key of a hash. Any object can be a key of a hash. That is why.
- why it does this not work when I replace the hash rocket with a colon

  Even if `Sequel.qualify(:meeting_graphs, :id)` turns out to be a symbol, the colon notation will not work because it is part of a literal notation. It is not a method or a keyword that works on Ruby objects that are already made.

Answer (score 3):

1. New hash syntax works only if key is a literal symbol.
2. `Sequel.qualify` returns qualifier object identifying column. It's possible since every object can be a hash key in Ruby.

Comment: I would say "a literal symbol"

Comment: Sequel.qualify returns an object

Comment: @dagda1 virtually everything in Ruby is object. What kind of object does `Sequel.qualify` return?

Comment: A QualifiedObject http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/QualifyingMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a keywords to the function and keywords use Hash syntax.

There are many ways to define hashes in ruby, and in the way you use a function one syntax does not work.

```
def return_one_symbol
   'one'.to_sym
end

hash_syntax1 = {:one => '1'}
hash_syntax2 = {one: '1'}
p hash_syntax1 # => {:one=>"1"}
p hash_syntax2 # => {:one=>"1"}

hash_syntax1_function = {return_one_symbol => '1'}
hash_syntax2_function = {return_one_symbol: '1'}
p hash_syntax1_function # => {:one=>"1"}
p hash_syntax2_function # => {:return_one_symbol=>"1"}
```

see this post for more info:

[Is there any difference between the `:key => "value"` and `key: "value"` hash notations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no)