# New Ruby syntax doesn't work everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to ask Ruby experts for explaination.

I can't use something like `"foo-bar": true`, but `foobar: true` works. Did anyone notice this?

### This works:

In new Ruby syntax we can replace this hash rocket:

```
<%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn" %>
                     ^-------------^
```

with this

```
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn" %>
                     ^----------^
```

### This doesn't:

Now, how about symbols with two words? This doesn't work - syntax error!

```
<%= f.submit "Save", "data-disable-with": "Saving..." %>
                     ^------------------------------^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between the \`:key => "value"\` and \`key: "value"\` hash notations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no)

Answer (score 4):

The JSON style `Hash` syntax is for `Hash`es whose keys are `Symbol`s which are valid Ruby identifiers. Your key is neither a `Symbol` (it's a `String`) nor a valid Ruby identifier (Ruby identifiers cannot contain a hyphen, because that creates an ambiguity with the binary infix `-` operator: does `a-b` mean the identifier `a-b` or does it mean "subtract `b` from `a`, i.e. `a.-(b)`?)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set the key as a string instead of a symbol.

Comment: I didn't see the minus symbols at first, sorry