# What is an efficient way, in vim, to change Ruby hashrockets into name:value notation?

Tags: ruby, vim

What is the most efficient way to change Ruby's hashrocket notation into the `name: 'value'` [notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675206/is-there-any-difference-between-the-key-value-and-key-value-hash-no) in vim?

Some examples:

```
{ 
  :id => site.id,
  :primary_domain => site.name,
  :wp_admin_url => site.wp_admin_url
}
{ 
  id: site.id,
  primary_domain: site.name,
  wp_admin_url: site.wp_admin_url
}


{ :id => site.id, :primary_domain => site.name }
{ id: site.id, primary_domain: site.name }


Site.find_by(:access_token => params[:access_token], :primary_domain => params[:primary_domain])
Site.find_by(access_token: params[:access_token], primary_domain:params[:primary_domain])
```

Do you have a macro for this? Some more efficient sequence then mine? Use search-replace?
The most efficient I can come up with, is quite manual and requires some repetiotion:

`ft:xpldf>`
go to the first `:`, delete it and paste it after the word, then move one character forward and delete the `=>` part. 
This needs to be repeated for each `:name => value` part in a Hash. And cannot be simply ran N times, because there might very well be some `:symbols` that need to remain, like in the last example.

How do you quickly change from the Hashrocket notation?

Comment: Tricky. I prepared a macro recording for you until I noticed that third example of yours. To handle such cases one needs a parser, which knows what syntactic element it is working on. I'm not able to create such with a simple recording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This substitution seems to do the trick on all three samples:

```
:%s/:\(\w\+\)\s*=>\s*/\1: /g
```

You can create a simple custom command out of it:

```
command! Notation %s/:\(\w\+\)\s*=>\s*/\1: /g
```

or a slightly smarter one:

```
command! -range=% Notation silent execute <line1>.','.<line2>.'s/:\(\w\+\)\s*=>\s*/\1: /g'
```

Comment: This is pretty much on the right track but it doesn't add single quotes to the value. `%s/:\(\w\+\) *=> *\([a-zA-Z0-9._-]\+\)/\1: '\2'/g` is along the right lines, but might need further tweaking.

Comment: Stupid me, I forgot the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I also learned about `help command` today. That was mostly the missing part.

Comment: Well quotes are not needed in the OP's samples but yeah, it needs a bit of tinkering to make it really generic.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: This regexp actually broke for me.

I had some code like: `Module::Class.where(:symbol => ...`

So the regexp tried to match from the `::` onward.

Instead, I used:

```
:1,$s/:\([^\:\s]\+\)\s\+=>/\1:/gc
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of iterative improvement, the following should also preserve whitespace between the key-value pairs (e.g. when rockets are tabbed over to align them, assuming space between the rocket and value doesn't need to be preserved):

:%s/:(\w+)(\s*)=>\s*/\1:\2/g

Should work with all of the following examples:

```
:key => value

Module::Class.where(:symbol => value)

{ 
  :id => site.id,
  :primary_domain => site.name
}

Site.find_by(:access_token => params[:access_token], :primary_domain => params[:primary_domain])

:symbol_one => some_method(:symbol_two).other_method(:symbol_3 => third_method(:symbol_4).attribute)

:to   => :processing_payment,
:from => [:awaiting_contact, :awaiting_payment]
```