# Ruby syntax with hash keys and symbols

Tags: ruby, literals

With the Rails expression `dependent: :destroy`, is `dependent` the hash key and `destroy` just a symbol?

Comment: This is pretty much the same as [**Is there any difference between the `:key => “value”` and `key: “value”` hash notations?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675206/479863), isn't it? Not quite a duplicate but fairly close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation introduced in Ruby 1.9 is just a shortcut, and you can see what it means using `irb`:

```
h = { dependent: :destroy }
# => { :dependent => :destroy }
```

They're both symbols. Don't forget that a hash can be keyed by *any object*, not necessarily a symbol or a string. This is completely different from most languages where the key will be coerced into something consistent.

Using that example you can see what the types of the keys and values are:

```
h.keys
# => [:dependent]

h.values
# => [:destroy]
```

They're all symbols in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy` is the same as `has_many(:orders, {:dependent => :destroy})`

`:dependent` is the key, `:destroy` the value of the hash passed as an argument to `has_many`.