# why there is a column ":" in front of key in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
aaa = { :one => "eins", :two => "zwei", :three => "drei" }
bbb = { one: "eins", two: "zwei", three: "drei" }
```

above are valid ruby code. at line 1, why there is ":" before "one"? What's the meaning?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html, https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Symbol.html

Comment: Also [**Is there any difference between the `:key => “value”` and `key: “value”` hash notations?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8675206/479863)

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Symbol.html), you could think of it as a special `string`. Symbols are often used as hash keys.

You could check out more on [Ruby Symbols vs. Strings](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/ruby-symbols-vs-strings-248842529fd9)

Answer (score 0):

In ruby hash is an association of key and value.

```
my_hash = { :key => "value" }
```

or

```
my_hash = { key: "value" }
```

more informations here : https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/hashes